# How i can get object in class List

Tags: c#

I created my class

```
class TxtEmail
{
    public TxtEmail(string firtFirstmail, string domain)
    {
        this.Firstmail = firtFirstmail;
        this.Domain = domain;

    }

    public string Firstmail { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }


    public string RetOneString()
    {
        return Firstmail + "@" + Domain;
    }
}
```

Then my class add to List Class

```
     class EmailDP : List<TxtEmail>
{
    List<TxtEmail> txtemail = new List<TxtEmail>();
    public void Add(string path)
    {

        txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user1", "google.ru"));
        txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user5555", "google.com"));
        txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user252", "outlook.com"));
        txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user3", "gmail.com"));
    }
   another methods ......
```

But then i created object my classes, he show 0 Count, Why? Where i make mistake and how i can get object in it?

```
EmailDP em1 = new EmailDP();
MessageBox.Show(em1.Count.ToString()); -> this show 0
foreach (var myob in em1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(myob.RetOneString());
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to call .Add() so nothing is added to the list so its length is 0.

Comment: You are adding to a private collection, not to the actual type.

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Comment: There is *almost* never a need to extend (inherit from) the type `List<T>`. Move the code you use in `Add` to the last block of code you have shown there and get rid of your type, use `List<TxtEmail>` directly.

Comment: Note: this is a perfect moment to learn how to use a debugger. Put a breakpoint in the part of code you assume should be run. See if it is. Add a breakpoint to where you think it should be called. Step into methods, run line by line. You’ll get a sense of what’s happening and can solve problems much faster by yourself.

Comment: List<TxtEmail> txtemail = new List<TxtEmail>(); change this to List<TxtEmail> txtemail = new List<TxtEmail>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two lists involved:

1. The class `EmailDP` itself derives from `List<TxtEmail>` and is therefore a list whose count you are displaying
2. The internal list `txtemail` to which you actually add the items, leaving `EmailDP` itself empty.

Change your class, so that it encapsulates the inner list.

```
class EmailDP
{
    private readonly List<TxtEmail> _txtemail = new List<TxtEmail>();

    public void Add(string path)
    {
        _txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user1", "google.ru"));
        _txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user5555", "google.com"));
        _txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user252", "outlook.com"));
        _txtemail.Add(new TxtEmail("user3", "gmail.com"));
    }

    public int Count => _txtemail.Count;

    public IEnumerable<TxtEmail> EmailTexts => _txtemail;

    // ... other methods
}
```

And of course you have to call `Add` at least once...

```
EmailDP em1 = new EmailDP();
em1.Add("some path");
em1.Add("another path");
MessageBox.Show(em1.Count.ToString());
foreach (var myob in em1.EmailTexts)
{
    MessageBox.Show(myob.RetOneString());
}
```

---

If you override `ToString` instead of creating a method `RetOneString`, you have the advantage that the `TxtEmail` objects will be displayed automatically at several places. I.e. in the debugger, in listboxes or in `Console.WriteLine`.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Firstmail + "@" + Domain;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have question. If i use private readonly List<TxtEmail> _txtemail = new List<TxtEmail>(); Then i created method `code` public string ReturnString()
        {
            string tmpstr = string.Empty;
            foreach (var tx in EmailTexts)
            {
                tmpstr = tx.RetOneString();
                
            }
            return tmpstr;
        } `code`   I use richTextBox1.AppendText(em1.RetOneString());  But foreach return only last object.

Comment: Because you are not concatenating (putting together) the strings. You are only assigning strings. So the last assignment replaces the previous ones. Replace `tmpstr = tx.RetOneString()` by `tmpstr += tx.RetOneString()`. Example: for `int sum = 0; sum = 4; sum = 5;` sum will be `5`. For `int sum = 0; sum += 4; sum += 5;` sum will be `9`.

Comment: `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y`.

Answer (score 0):

Your EmailDP is-a List and also has-a List and I don't think you mean for both of those to be true. It's a question of inheritance vs composition. Do you need your class to be a list or can it contain a list instead?

If you want your class to be-a List, then in your add method, you can do:

```
this.Add(new TxtEmail("user1", "google.ru")); ...
```

If you want your class to contain-a List then you can remove the inheritance of List

```
class EmailDP 
{
    ...
```

And then make your list public so it is accessible:

```
public List<TxtEmail> txtemail = new List<TxtEmail>();
```

And then get the count from the list contained within:

```
MessageBox.Show(em1.textemail.Count.ToString());
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the Add Method which fills your array.
Also do not inherit the  List as you do not need this.

```
 EmailDP em1 = new EmailDP();
em1.Add(string.Empty);
    MessageBox.Show(em1.Count.ToString()); -> You will get items you added in the Add Method
    foreach (var myob in em1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myob.RetOneString());
    }
```

Comment: Probably because it is wrong. `em1.Count` will still be zero as items are added to a private collection and NOT the object collection.

Comment: Oops... yes if he makes it public, the he would be able to access it